# How to convert a list of element to a list of lists

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list which looks like {1,2,3,4,5} and so on. Is there any quick way of changing it to {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}}? Thanks

Comment: v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};Map[List[#] &, v] or List /@ v

Comment: 'lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}'.  One way:  `Transpose[{lst}]`.  Another: `Thread[List[lst]]`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
In[77]:= a = {}                                                                                     

Out[77]= {}

In[78]:= b = {1,2,3,4,5}                                                                            

Out[78]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

In[79]:= For[i=1, i<Length[b]+1, i++, AppendTo[a, {Part[b,i]}]]                                     

In[80]:= a                                                                                          

Out[80]= {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}
```

You can use a For[] to loop over n total elements and append the n-th element of your list as a list to a new list.
If you dont iterate from 1 to Length + 1 you get

`Out[88]= {{List}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}` back

There may be a better way to do this.